# inet_ntop printing incorrect IPv6 address

Tags: c

I seem to be getting back bad IPv6 character strings from inet_ntop especially with addresses where it tries to drop sequences of zeros in favor of "::".

Here is the code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t ip[4] = {0xe0e0e0e0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0x0, 0x1};
    char addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = "";

    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, ip, addr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("address = %s",addr);
    return 0;
}
```

When i run this i get the following output;

```
address = address = e0e0:e0e0:f0f0:f0f0::100:0
```

This looks quite wrong to me and i would have expect something like;

```
address = e0e0:e0e0:f0f0:f0f0::1
```

Does anyone know whats wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: [Mind the byte order!](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The comment, pay attention to byte order is correct. You should also use the `struct in6_addr` for the IP address really. Here is an example initialising that as a sequence of bytes, which gives the expected output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main (void)
{
    const struct in6_addr ip = { 0xe0, 0xe0, 0xe0, 0xe0,
                                 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0,
                                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 };
    //const uint32_t ip[4] = { 0xe0e0e0e0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0x0, 0x1 };
    char addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &ip, addr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("address = %s",addr);
    return 0;
}
```

`gcc main.c && ./a.out` results in: `address = e0e0:e0e0:f0f0:f0f0::1`

Here's a quick example to compare the byte ordering on an x86 machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main (void)
{
    const struct in6_addr ip_uint8 = { 0xe0, 0xe0, 0xe0, 0xe0,
                                       0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0,
                                       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                                       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 };
    const uint32_t ip_uint32[4] = { 0xe0e0e0e0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0x0, 0x1 };
    char addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &ip_uint8, addr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("address = %s\n",addr);

    unsigned char* b = (unsigned char*)&ip_uint8;
    printf("address bytes uint8 :");
    for( int i=0; i<16; i++) {
      printf(" %2.2X", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    b = (unsigned char*)&ip_uint32;
    printf("address bytes uint32:");
    for( int i=0; i<16; i++) {
      printf(" %2.2X", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Gives the output:

```
address = e0e0:e0e0:f0f0:f0f0::1
address bytes uint8 : E0 E0 E0 E0 F0 F0 F0 F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01
address bytes uint32: E0 E0 E0 E0 F0 F0 F0 F0 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
```

The example words of repetitive bytes like `0xe0e0e0e0` don't do you any favours when trying to debug these sorts of problems, `0x01020304` would give you a much better idea of what was going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This is Network byte order issue. try this code.

```
char addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = "";
uint32_t ip[4] = {0xe0e0e0e0, 0xf0f0f0, 0x0, 0x1};
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    ip[i] = htonl(ip[i]);
}
inet_ntop(AF_INET6, ip, addr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
printf("address = %s\n",addr);
```