# inet_ntop returning partically incorrect IPv6 address

Tags: c, posix

I am aware of this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848281/inet-ntop-printing-incorrect-ipv6-address), but the answers do not make sense and are possibly for a different problem.

In my iOS app I connect to a server using CFSockets and wish to show the remote address of the server. When using IPv4 it works as expected, but there are weird results with IPv6 where the network prefix of the address are correct, but the host bits are completely different.

```c
int sock_fd = <...> // Assume I already have the fd
struct sockaddr addr;
socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(addr);
getpeername(sock_fd, &addr, &addr_len);
char addressString[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&addr)->sin6_addr, addressString, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

What I expected was `2607:f2f8:a4c8::2` but what I get is an address with the correct network prefix but different host bits each time, e.g:

```
               vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv Random?
2607:f2f8:a4c8:0:c400:13b0:f6c5:afa
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Correct
```

Comment: Do you know that it's common for devices to have multiple IP addresses on the same network? Do you know what IPv6 privacy addresses are?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'm connecting to a website on the internet. Using curl I see the correct IP address. `Connected to v6.burn.net (2607:f2f8:a4c8::2) port 80 (#0)`

Comment: That doesn't address either of my points.

Comment: Can you dump the contents of `addr`, either with a print or a debugger? What's in it, and does it match the text output?

Comment: Also add error checks to your calls to `getpeername` and `inet_ntop`. Such things can be surprising sometimes.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We cannot guess what your problem is.  When I `getaddrinfo("v6.burn.net", NULL, { .ai_family = AF_INET6, ... }, ...)`, for example, my `sockaddr_in6` results _ntop_ to the expected 2607:f2f8:a4c8::2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man page of `getpeername(2)` gives a hint as to why this is happening:

> The address_len parameter should be initialized to indicate the amount of space pointed to by address.  On return it contains the actual size of the address returned (in bytes).
>
> The address is truncated if the buffer provided is too small.

The size of `struct sockaddr` is too small for IPv6 addresses and will result in the address being truncated.

You need to use `struct sockaddr_storage` with `getpeername` rather than just `struct sockaddr`

```c
struct sockaddr_storage addr;
socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(addr);
getpeername(socket, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addr_len)
```